# Ubuntu 13.04 on Gateway NV57H44u turns monitor idle even when told not to

Tags: 13.04, screen, power-management, idle

The screen is shutting off when power settings are **NOT** set to make it turn off.

I am running **Ubuntu 13.04** on an **Gateway NV57H44u**. For some reason my screen keeps going to sleep (going blank) after 10 minutes of being idle, but I have the screen saver turned off and I have the power settings set to **NEVER** turn off or dim the monitor.

I also checked to make sure that there wasn't a setting in the BIOS that could be doing this and there are no power saving settings in my BIOS.

Thankz.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share both screenshots for "Brightness & Lock" and "Power" from the System Configuration options.

Also, did you look into the /var/log/syslog to check if there is anything that could lead you to the root cause of your screen being powered off ?

Two more things:

Is there any script running on the crontab that could turn off the screen ?

Is there any application that could turn off the screen?

Regards.